# text string / word cloud ignore line break symbol

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I have an implementation of the popular d3 [word cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud). It has been working great for documents that are very lengthy, but I have been having an issue when I tried to re-purpose the word cloud to visualize a very simple txt file of the following format:

```
interesting. interesting. interesting.
boring. boring.
amazing. amazing. amazing.
stupid. stupid. stupid.
average. average.
disappointing.
(ect...)
```

It's basically just a txt file that has around 20 words. Each word repeats anywhere from 1 to 5 times. I would like this information to govern the sizing of the font (repeated 5 times = big font, 1 time = small font). When I put all the words on the same line, the resulting word cloud strangely makes all words the same font size. So I started to play around with it and tried a few different things. The closest I got to the desired effect was with the above txt format, having a line break after each new word.

This did result in the correct font sizing, but it also created a new problem. When I passed `word_count` object to the console log, I got something like this:

```
"⏎boring":1,
"boring":1,
"⏎stupid":1,
"stupid":2,
```

This means that the word cloud has repeated words in the visual (for example, the word "stupid" in large font size and also "stupid" in small font size). To make things more confusing, this behavior was isolated to a few words. Some words did not have the line break sign in front of them (even though I still hit enter in notepad when I made the txt in the same exact was as the ones that did wind up with the ⏎ sign.)

My next stab at fixing this was to add the "⏎" sign to the list of ignored words, hoping that would make the word cloud library treat them as if they were the same. Unfortunately for me, the problem persisted.

That sums it up pretty well; it's also really easy to reproduce, just need notepad and copy and paste my above words to see what I'm talking about.

Let me know if anyone has ideas for troubleshooting further.

Minimalist Block: 
https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/cd644316f52465495f39c8fc27f04de8

(refreshing page will randomize the layout)

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @mkaran Updated with a link to a functional block.

Comment: *"When I put all the words on the same line, the resulting word cloud strangely makes all words the same font size"* Not for me: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/8af3add631f81c4bf2bdc5266234fb98

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's perplexing. Thanks for posting your block, I'll see what's amiss hopefully.

Comment: All I did was removing all the line breaks and making the text a single line. Also, I removed that huge regex.